# How to make ImageButtons bounds wrap around the image

Tags: android

I'm making a GUI for an android app, this GUI contains a five direction ImageButtons  arround and imageview how i can make design for this circle below(look at the following image):[image]

Comment: what exactly You want to know and what have You tried?

Comment: See this: http://av.victorhaggqvist.com/2012/10/radial-menu-widget/index.html

Comment: Thanks very match I will try it , it more useful